# What did I do? chmod

Tags: permissions

I misstyped and entered this command.

`sudo chmod -R -755 /usr/local/nagios/libexec/*`

Now it seems like the normal user "nagios" can not see any files in this folder.
But the user is owner and the rights on 777.

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 nagios nagios 4096 Apr 30 17:43 libexec
```

But when I try to execute the file:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe
-bash: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe: No such file or directory
```

The file did have this rights:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nagios nagios  63845 Apr 30 17:43 check_nrpe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have completely removed the read and executable rights for groups and others and all rights for the owner for all files and folders in `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/` but not for `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/` itself.

It can no longer be ascertained, as the rights actually denominated. This command makes it reversed, but it may be that too many rights are then assigned.

```
sudo chmod -R +755 /usr/local/nagios/libexec/*
```

Comment: Omg sometimes it is really better to do a break.
I will try it out next week monday since I am not in the office any longer. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @user3772108 come on, give me an upvote ;)

Comment: wow i can finally upvote answers! here is my first upvote for you. thanks again for your great help.

Comment: but one more question: why i didn't see that with the command `ls -la` ?

Comment: Which `ls -la`?

Comment: The built in command to list all files in a directory. I used the command `ls -la` to see what permissions the files had. But as you can see at my question dialog the rights where looking correct with `-rwxrwxrwx 1 nagios nagios  63845 Apr 30 17:43 check_nrpe` as example. Normally I would think the user and group should not be displayed in this case?

Comment: You have changed the permissions *in* /usr/local/nagios/libexec/ but not for /usr/local/nagios/libexec/ itself.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. The file "check_nrpe" is in the folder libexec. This content was listed by me with `ls -la /usr/local/nagios/libexec`. In this list I could see owner and group. And that's the point. It still displayed owner and group as nagios, when the file does not longer have this owner and group.

Comment: That's interesting. Which filesystem?

Comment: ext4 and it is in a volume group.